# Script to check if it is a directory or file and then process the rest of the script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to rsync content on a specific directory to a different server and creating a script so that it is automated. 
My script will check if contents of the the directory has files or folders and in-turn move them using rsync. Below,

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `ls /root/tags/` ; do
if [ -f "$i" ]
then
  echo "this is a file and I'll run a script if it is a file"
else
if [ -d "$i" ]
then
  echo "this is a dir and I'll run a script if it is a directory"
fi
fi
done
```

As you can see, my knowledge on shell scripts aren't anything to shout about but I'm trying to get this working.

Comment: It should have been <code> if [ -f /root/tags/$i ]; then echo " this is a file and I'll run the script if it is a file",</code>

Comment: Use of `ls -l *` in `for` is not needed. You may use `for i in /root/tags/*` instead.

Comment: I'm not experienced with rsync but it probably has an option to do what you need without having to write any code.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is

```
cd /root/tags
for i in * ; do
  if [ -f "$i" ]; then
    echo "this is a file and I'll run a script if it is a file"
  elif [ -d "$i" ]; then
    echo "this is a dir and I'll run a script if it is a directory"
  fi
done
```

And that is the same as

```
path="/root/tags"
for i in "${path%/}"/* ; do
  if [ -f "$i" ]; then
    echo "this is a file and I'll run a script if it is a file"
  elif [ -d "$i" ]; then
    echo "this is a dir and I'll run a script if it is a directory"
  fi
done
```

Which I found like a good reusable code.

Comment: +1 for getting `ls` out of the `for`. But, there's no need to `cd`, `for i in /root/tags/*;` works fine by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of `else if` is incorrect, it should be `elif`

```
if [ -f "$i" ]; then
  echo "this is a file and I'll run a script if it is a file"
elif [ -d "$i" ]; then
  echo "this is a dir and I'll run a script if it is a directory"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

To get sure that files with spaces in their names don't cause problems, use something like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | while read -d "" file ; do
    if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
        echo "$file is a file and I'll run a script if it is a file"
    elif [ -d "$file" ] ; then
        echo "$file is a dir and I'll run a script if it is a directory"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Nope. Try `ls | cat` to see how `ls` behaves when its output is not a terminal. Worse, you should [never parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), it will break.

Comment: Yeah I see. preapring a find example